# error: use of undeclared identifier 'groupRectangles'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to group multiple rectangles in opencv. Here is what I'm doing

```
void groups_draw(Mat &src, vector<Rect> &groups)
{

    vector<Rect> rects;
    for (int i=(int)groups.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
     {
        rects.push_back(groups.at(i));
    }
    groupRectangles(rects, 1, 0.2);
}
```

But I get the following error:

error: use of undeclared identifier 'groupRectangles'

The headers in my file are:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include  "opencv2/text.hpp"
#include  "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include  "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include  <vector>
#include  <iostream>
#include  <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::text;
```

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/61308/undefined-reference-to-cvgrouprectangles/ Any of this relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [groupRectangles](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles) is declared in `opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp`.

You can, however, use the *include all* `opencv2/opencv.hpp`.